# Why does custom plugin fail to fork a Java process?

Tags: java, jetty, sbt, sbt-plugin

I wrote sbt plugin that use

```
Fork.java.fork(forkOptions, Seq("-cp", (deps mkString File.pathSeparator) + File.pathSeparator + cp ) ++ args)
```

start Jetty.
It report an error

> Error: Could not find or load main class  org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner

but the `jetty-runner-9.2.1.v20140609.jar` is on CLASSPATH. The command is like:

```
jre/bin/java  -cp .ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-runner/jars/jetty-runner-9.2.1.v20140609.jar:(my project class path) org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner (webapp path)
```

I copied it into my shell and it ran well.

Comment: `debug` the session!